# Upload an image with my own size to vimeo

Tags: upload, size, settings, thumbnails, vimeo

Is it possible to upload an image with my own size to vimeo?

For instance, I want my `thumbnail_medium` to be 400x400, but every time I am uploading the 400x400 I am getting the 200x150 after retrieving the video data by the url `https://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/myVideoIdGoesHere.json`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing '200x150.webp' at the end of `thumbnail_medium` with '400x400'

That postfix is what determines the size. I'd recommend indexing on '_' and appending the dimensions you desire (the '.webp' is unnecessary). Something like this...

`const newURL = oldURL.substring(0, oldURL.indexOf('_')) + '_400x400'`

If you look at `thumbnail_small`, the only difference in the url is a change of the postfix

Comment: Hello. Thank you for the attempt to help me. I would like to be able to change that on the vimeo side, but not in code. That is the purpose of this question. As of right now it seems that what I want is impossible.

Comment: Ah my mistake. Unfortunately you are correct, it is impossible to change the default thumbnail sizes of that api response